# Is there way to call DataUsageSummary from 'adb shell am' without any additional action?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I want to call Data usage screen from 'adb shell am start' command.
But due to its base class is Fragment, command always returns first Settings screen.
So is there any way to call DataUsageSummary from 'adb shell am' without any additional action to manifest?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
adb shell am start -n "com.android.settings/.Settings\"\$\"DataUsageSummaryActivity"
```